# Powermock Whitebox invocation with null parameter

Tags: null, mockito, powermock, white-box

I'm trying to test a private method and have the following setup:

```
public class MyClass {
  private boolean myprivatemethod(ClassB classBObject, boolean b) {
    // do stuff here
    someOtherMethod();
  }

  private void someOtherMethod() {
    // more stuff
  }
}

final MyClass testsubject = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
// spy is needed because "someOtherMethod" is mocked 
// which is not shown here for simplicity
ClassB classBObject = mock(ClassB.class);

boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(testsubject, "myprivatemethod", classBObject, true);
```

This works nice until I try to run the method with `null` as the ClassB object:

```
boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(testsubject, "myprivatemethod", null, true);
```

This results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.checkIfParameterTypesAreSame(WhiteboxImpl.java:2432)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1934)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getBestMethodCandidate(WhiteboxImpl.java:1025)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:948)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:882)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:713)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at test.myproject.TestMyClass.testMyClass(TestMyClass.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit3RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit3RunnerDelegateImpl.java:113)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:165)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.PowerMockSuite.run(PowerMockSuite.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I'm using Powermockito 1.5.
Is there any way to execute the method with `null` as parameter?

Comment: Did either answer help you out?

Comment: I'll try your answers out as soon as I can, can take a couple of days until I have time for it, though ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using argument matchers instead:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;

//...

boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(testsubject,
    "myprivatemethod", isNull(ClassB.class), eq(true));
```

Once you use Matchers for any of the arguments, you have to use them for all arguments. This is noted in the Mockito documentation [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) (see subsection *Warning on argument matchers*).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this :

```
Object[] params = {null, true};
```

then :

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(testsubject, "myprivatemethod", params);
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerMock is unable to match for the parameter types. You can explicitly tell the parameter types like this -

```
ClassB classBObject = null;
boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(testsubject,
        "myprivatemethod", new Class<?>[] { ClassB.class,Boolean.class},classBObject,true);
```